# Facebook dev settings: Unable to add domain in facebook app settings because of other required parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

My app is still in development mode and I've been attempting to add `localhost` to **App Domains** for development in **Basic Settings**. This is to allow localhost callbacks for login requests during development.

I've tried without setting this but facebook shows me a message explicitly saying that I have to set the App Domains field.

But then, the other fields, namely **Privacy Policy URL** and **User data deletion** start showing parameter required error and can't seem to save save changes because of this. This is stupid. Do I really have to setup a hosting and have some kind of placeholder pages before I can even start development?

Comment: You should be able to insert any arbitrary URLs for privacy policy and user data deletion URL. As long as they are publicly reachable, Facebook should not complain at this point. (Make sure to switch them for real URLs before you submit your app for review or take it live though.)

Comment: Once I added a random active URL it went through. Thanks.